# How to use Google Place api Current place in background

Tags: android, service, background, google-api, google-places-api

I am not a native English speaker and I am writing with a translator. I want you to understand if the context is strange.

I want to periodically use the Google Place API in the background.

MainActivity.java

```
private static final String LOG_TAG = "PlacesAPIActivity";
private static final int GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID = 0;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private TextView txtView,txtView2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_places_api);
    txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtview);
    txtView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtview2);
    Button currentButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.currentButton);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .enableAutoManage(this, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
            .build();
    currentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                            PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                } else {
                    //callPlaceDetectionApi();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
                    startService(intent);

                }

            }
        }
    });
}

public void callPlaceDetectionApi() throws SecurityException {
    PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
            .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
            for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                float temp = placeLikelihood.getLikelihood();
                String tempName = placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName().toString();
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.format("Place '%s' with " +
                                "likelihood: %g",
                        placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                        placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
                if (temp <= a)
                {
                    rightplace = placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName().toString();
                    a = temp;
                    rightplace = tempName;
                }


            }
            txtView.setText(rightplace);
            txtView2.setText(Float.toString(a));
            likelyPlaces.release();
        }
    });
}
```

MyService.java

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    return null;
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    myServiceHandler handler = new myServiceHandler();
    thread = new ServiceThread(handler);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    thread.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    myActivity = new MyActivity();
}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    thread.stopForever();
    thread = null;
}

class myServiceHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "testest", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        myActivity.getInstance().callPlaceDetectionApi();
    }
};
```

MyActivity.java

public class MyActivity extends Application {

```
private static volatile MainActivity mainActivity;

public static MainActivity getInstance()
{
    if(mainActivity == null)
    {
        synchronized (MyActivity.class)
        {
            if (mainActivity == null)
            {
                mainActivity = new MainActivity();

            }
        }

    }
    return mainActivity;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}
```

I do not know why the App hangs up when running Service.
I need your help.